# How to use regex to replace text between tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to replace some text in a string that represents a div tag that may or may not also include style and class attributes. For example,

```
var s = "<div style='xxx' class='xxx'>replaceThisText<div>
```

If it were just the tag, I believe I could just do this:

```
str = str.replace(/<div>[\s\S]*?<\/div>/, '<div>' + newText+ '<\/div>');
```

But how do I take the attributes into account?

Comment: Parse it into a DOM element then change `.innerHTML` or `.textContent`.

Comment: [Obligatory link to the famous StackOverflow answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1954610)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a temporary element with your string as HTML content then get the div within it to update content after updating the content get back the HTML of temporary element.

```js
var s = "<div style='xxx' class='xxx'>replaceThisText<div>";

// create a temporary div element
var temp = document.createElement('div');

// set content as string
temp.innerHTML = s;

// get div within the temporary element
// and update the content within the div
temp.querySelector('div').innerHTML = 'newText';

// get back the current HTML content in the
// temporary div element
console.log(temp.innerHTML)
```

Why not regex?

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

[Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Comment: What about `temp.firstChild.innerHTML='newText'` other than using a `querySelector`?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek : that's also fine if there is no leading whitespace or text in the content... otherwise it may be textNode

Answer (score 0):

Regex will never be a good decision to parse *html* content.
Consider the following short solution using `DOMParser` object(for browsers which support `DOMParser` implementation, see [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/DOMParser#Browser_compatibility)):

```js
var s = "<div style='xxx' class='xxx'>replaceThisText<div>",
    tag = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(s, 'text/html').querySelector('.xxx');

tag.textContent = 'newText';  // replacing with a new text
console.log(tag.outerHTML);   // outputs the initial tag representation with replaced content
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/DOMParser